# WordPress stick menu bar css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

What should I write in css if I want to stick the menu bar(including site logo) when scrolling and I want to change the bar into black background colour and white for font.

I hope the below information is related to menu bar.Please help, thank you.

```
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul li a,
ol li a {
    color: #545454;
}
ul li a:hover,
ol li a:hover {
    color: #c0b596;
}
ul ul,
ol ol,
ul ol,
ol ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
caption, th {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
}
td, th {
    padding: 8px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
a img {
    border: 0 none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code

Comment: What is the name of your theme? We need the class or ID of your menu...